# How to add 'running log' ( console ) to my WCF server?

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

I wrote WCF server. 
I want to be able to see all the calls from the client ( for debug ) in run-time - so i thought that the best solution will be to add some ability to flush the information to console.

( i want to add some 'black' console like the console that appear when creating console appliaction - and not in the output of the visual sdudio )

How can i add now this console ? 
How can i control the console ( write to console , show / hide to console ) ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using log4net (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). It's a great and stable logging tool which allows you to configure your logging settings through xml. You can just add a console Appender to your application, restart and it does console logging for you. If you want text, take text.

By the way, if you use tools like baretail (http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) working with log files is really nice and you won't need to run your service in console mode to debug/monitor it.